# Clickable button to reveal "advanced options" in an external search form?

Tags: button

I'm a librarian with some limited experience with basic html and css. I am trying to rebuild our main search feature so that it is more usable.

I am trying to get "advanced search" options to toggle on and off so that our search feature works similar to this library website: https://zsr.wfu.edu/ (click the down arrow next to "What can we help you find?).

This is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/nmb2p7ys/2/ . I can get the advanced search to display with a mouse hover, but that's all. I am fairly certain the problem is with the JS, but I really have no idea and I've tried everything.

```
$("#oneschddtest").click(function()
{   

$("#testpanel").toggle();     
});
```

I'm guessing I made some elementary mistake(s), especially with the JS. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the focus event on the `<input>` and show the `testpanel`:

```
$("#lindellOneSearch-search-str").focus(function()
{   
    $("#testpanel").show();     
});
```

Then you can toggle the `testpanel` when the user clicks the arrow button:

```
$(".OneSearchdropbtn").click(function(){
    $("#testpanel").toggle();
});
```

Although it seems to be working you have another problem, which is when the user selects the options in the dropdown menu it toggles out the dropdown.

This happens because your html is not correct, and all your dropdown html is inside the arrow button. So when you click the options you are actually also clicking in the arrow as well.

If you inspect the example site you gave, you will see that they structured it differently, and separated both things. I suggest restructuring your html to solve this additional problem.

Comment: Thank you Isac! Would you mind forking my fiddle and sharing the fiddle you made where it works?  I tried adding what you suggested and still could not get this to work. And thank you for pointing out the html problem, I will definitely correct that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @SVanCleve I also added `jQuery` in the fiddle javascript options, which wasn't selected. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qorw2bw/1/)

Comment: Thank you! You truly made my day.

Comment: @SVanCleve No problem. Best of luck on your website.